# Java equivalent to Doug Crockford's cycle.js

Tags: java, javascript, json

I'm using JSON as my serialization technology between JavaScript and Java. I have an object graph that I want to serialize (not and object tree) and I want to maintain object references when it is serialized/deserialized.

Douglas Crockford's cycle.js seems like a good solution for this.
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

But there is no equivalent library on the Java side that I can find. I'm currently using Gson and would like to use an adapter but so far I can't find one.

One the Java side there is the Jackson ObjectIdentity feature.
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity

I could switch from Gson to Jackson; but I can't find an equivalent JavaScript library.

Does anyone know of a Java library that is equivalent to Douglas Crockford's cylce.js? Or a JavaScript library that is equivalent to Jackson ObjectIdentity?

Comment: Would be better if you included an example of what cycle.js actually does

Comment: I was looking for the same solution. Ended up using JSOG. But personally i still prefer the cycle.js implementation.

Comment: To apply to legacy code without any additional code(include annotation), json-io could be a good alternative. 
https://github.com/jdereg/json-io

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [JSOG](https://github.com/jsog/jsog) which supports Java jackson serialization and has worked well for me.